# How to use memchr with 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array, find

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

In C++ I can search elements in single dimensional array using memchr.

```
char* pStart, char* pEnd;
 //find first available register
 char *pCur,*p1;
  pCur=p1=pStart;
 while(pCur<pEnd)
  {
    //find 0
    p1 = (char*)memchr(pCur,0x0,pEnd-pCur);
    pCur=p1;
  }
```

I have 2 dimensional array e.g. int array[200][2].

How to use memchr to find all 0 element in this array?

Comment: To begin with, the `chr` in `memchr` stands for *character*. You can't use it to search for `int` values.

Comment: As for your problem, why not simply loop over the outer array and check if one or both of the inner array values are zero? Can probably be simplified using some [standard C++ algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: what language is it really? Questions clearly states C++ but then the wrong tag has been removed

Comment: You should use `bsearch` not `memchr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `memchr()` at all on an array of `int`s, since they are larger than one byte each.

Also, this reads like an old-school C question; in C++ you should probably look into using some more advanced container type.

For a C answer, you would probably need to just loop over the array and search, that's the most straight-forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

The function `memchr` as it follows from its name searches a character in a character array. You can not use it to find an object of the type `int` because the function does not deal with such objects.

You should write an appropriate function yourself.

For example it can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * find( const int *a, size_t n, int value )
{
    const int *first = a;

    while ( first != a + n && *first != value ) ++ first;

    return first == a + n ? NULL : ( int * )first;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[4][2] =
    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 0 },
        { 4, 5 },
        { 0, 6 }
    };
    const size_t M = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t N = sizeof( *a ) / sizeof( **a );

    int value = 0;
    int *p = ( int * )a;

    for ( ; ( p = find( p, M * N - ( p - ( int * )a ), value ) ) != NULL; ++p )
    {
        size_t m = ( p - ( int * )a ) / N;
        size_t n = ( p - ( int * )a ) % N;

        printf( "a[%zu][%zu] is equal to %d\n", m, n, value );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a[1][1] is equal to 0
a[3][0] is equal to 0
```

Using this function you can find any value in any multi-dimensional integer array.

The function just interprets a multi-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array and returns pointer to the searched element. You can calculate "coordinates" of this element using this pointer and knowing dimensions of the array as it is shown for a two-dimensional array in the demonstrative program.

By analogy with the standard C function `bsearch` you can write a general search function that can deal with arrays of any integer type.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void * find( const void *value, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size )
{
    const unsigned char *first = base;

    while ( first != ( const unsigned char * )base + nmemb * size && 
            memcmp( first, value, size ) != 0 ) first += size;

    return first == ( const unsigned char * )base + nmemb * size ? NULL : ( void * )first;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[4][2] =
    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 0 },
        { 4, 5 },
        { 0, 6 }
    };
    const size_t M = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t N = sizeof( *a ) / sizeof( **a );

    int value = 0;

    for ( int *p = ( int * )a; ( p = find( &value, p, M * N - ( p - ( int * )a ), sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL; ++p )
    {
        size_t m = ( p - ( int * )a ) / N;
        size_t n = ( p - ( int * )a ) % N;

        printf( "a[%zu][%zu] is equal to %d\n", m, n, value );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
a[1][1] is equal to 0
a[3][0] is equal to 0
```

In C++ you can use the same approach with the reinterpretation of a multidimensional array as a one-dimensional array and applying the standard algorithm `std::find` declared in the header `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 0):

Array is a continuous chunk of memory and it does not matter how many dimensions it has.

Example for 2D

more universal one:

```
void *mymemobj(void *haystack, void *needle, size_t objectsize, size_t elements)
{
    size_t cursor = 0;
    while (cursor < elements)
    {
        if (!memcmp(haystack, needle, objectsize)) return haystack;
        haystack = ((uint8_t *)haystack + objectsize);
        cursor++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *findInTwoDimentionalArray(void *array, void *needle, size_t objectsize, size_t rows, size_t columns, int *x, int *y)
{
    int result = 0;
    void *tmp = my_memobj(array, needle, objectsize, rows * columns);

    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        *x = -1;
        *y = -1;
        result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t pos = ((uint8_t *)tmp - (uint8_t *)array) / objectsize;
        *x = pos % columns;
        *y = pos / columns;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

---

or just char

```
char *findInTwoDimentionalArray(char *array, int val, int rows, int columns, int *x, int *y)
{
    char *tmp = memchr(array, value, rows * columns);

    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        *x = -1;
        *y = -1;
    }
    else 
    { 
        size_t pos = tmp - array;
        *x = pos % columns;
        *y = pos / columns;
    }
    return tmp;
}


void printAll(int val)
{
    char array[20][50];

    char *tmp = &array[0][0];
    int x, y;

    while (tmp < (&array[0][0] + 20 * 50) && (tmp = findInTwoDimentionalArray(tmp, val, 20, 50, &x, &y)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("value %d was found at x = %d and y = %d\n", val, x, y);
        tmp++;
    }
}
```